# How to recognize if user already exist or not with FirebasUI?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Im using FirebaseUI for auth flow in my app. I faced the problem that all users who came back and try to log in need to follow as a new user flow. After click **SUBMIT** button on FirebaseUI screen it give **OK_STATUS**. But how to recognize did user logged in as existing user or he just created a new account?

Thats my code

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (data != null) {
            //TODO HERE SUPPOSE TO BE FOR A NEW USER ONLY NOT EXISTING ONE
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("registration_completed", null);
                mPresenter.saveUser();
                reload();
            } else {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("registration_error_type", "registration failed");
                firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("registration_failed", bundle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49347535/firebaseui-auth-how-to-know-if-account-is-from-a-new-signup-or-existing-user

Answer (score 0):

That's something you should keep track of on your own.  You can pretty easily store per-user information in a database.  You can simply query the database for a record that matches their UID assigned by Firebase Authentication.  If the record doesn't exist, you know it's a new user, and then you can create that record.  If the record does exist, you know it's a returning user.